# How to customize a <nixpkgs> package configureFlags

Tags: nix

I need to modify `configureFlags` of `pcre` package from `<nixpkgs>`.
I've tried to do it with .nixpkgs/config.nix file as described [here](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-modify-via-packageOverrides):

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    pcre = pkgs.pcre.overrideDerivation (attrs: {
      configureFlags = [
        "--disable-jit"
        "--enable-unicode-properties"
        "--disable-cpp"
      ];
      doCheck = "";
    });
  };
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I run `nix-build -p pcre` it builds the package twice: with --disable-jit and with --enable-jit. When I run `nix-build -p stdenv` customizations in config.nix are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`stdenv` is special in that it is used to build "normal" packages (and you are overriding `pcre` as "normal" package). So, to make customizations work, you have to patch `stdenv`!

For example, you can use one of the functions from [adapters](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/stdenv/adapters.nix).

If you want to embed `pcre` more deeply, you have to look into [staged `stdenv` building](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/stdenv/linux/default.nix)